# AS3 trace, specially errors message to a textbox

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, trace

I'd like to be able to redirect the traces, and even more then traces the flash error reports to a text-box inside my flash app, so I can see the bug report in a computer that doesn't have flash-player debugger version or flashbug installed.

Any error message that comes on in my app should show in this textbox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own error reporting class with a simple TextField and an event listener which will update your TextField content by returning the text property of a custom event or a [Signal](http://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) you would dispatch , wherever you need to add a trace statement in your application.

For simplicity's sake and since this is only used as a development tool , create a Singleton whose sole purpose will be to dispatch & receive events.

Edit:
Re: a global error handler, you could have a look at this , but it seems that it's still in beta   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html

Comment: But this would mean that I'd have to "try catch" all of the places where I'm expecting error. I'd like to see all errors including, flash errors in the textbox. I can do what you refereed here, and it seems like the right thing to do. I'm just wondering if it is possible to create a class that catches errors automatically.

Comment: Just got around looking at this. Looks complex, but surely will give it a shot.
Thanks @PatrickS

Answer (score 1):

For traces, you can try to declare your own trace function, which will accumulate messages and show them when some key is pressed. For exceptions, they must be caught and traced. In AIR, there is global exception handler, but not in Flash.

Comment: Is there any way we could create a exception handler our self or someone maybe has created it. This would make life much easier for me, specially debugging. ;)

Comment: You can wrap your code in try/catch blocks, but only your code. It's impossible to 'inject' them into loaded swf. So, swf must support debugging in some way.